# user authentication failed for MasterCard type in PayPal PayFlow link Test Transaction

Tags: paypal, payflowlink

I got the below message after transaction failed,

RESULT=1 RESPMSG=User+authentication+failed.

Used MasterCard test Credit Card Number. I searched and tried to find a solution.But couldn't

Please help me to find a solution,

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

This typically means that you are not passing across the correct credentials.  You would need to double check these and make sure they are correct.  If you see this transaction show up in your Payflow account and it says user authentication, then this usually means that you do not have your processor information set up on the account correctly, and you may need to double check the processor information.  However, this shouldn't be an issue if this is a test being ran again the test server.

Comment: The details like Credit Card number, CSC , required info are entered correctly.I have done double check.If the reason is processor information means, how to check it.Please guide me

Comment: In regards to the correct credentials, I was referring to your credentials such as user, vendor, partner, and password.  As for checking the processor information, you would need to compare your processor set up information with what is set in your account.  If you can provide a transaction ID for a test transaction you ran either through API or thru the account, I can pull it up and take a look at it on my side.

Comment: This the transaction ID - V19F4BA6FB25

Comment: Initially MasterCard was not set up on the account.  MasterCard has now been mapped to this account.  Give it an hour and try to run another test.  If you still get a failure, you will need to confirm your processor set up info on your account.  If that all matches, then you need to contact your processor and verify it with them, and verify that you are set up to process MasterCard transactions through them.

Comment: Thank you.I will try it after 1 hour